Counter example for 2D rotation not being vector?
Without use of complex maths, it is physically possible to demonstrate that 3d rotation is  not a vector by the example of rotating a cuboid object on 3 directions, which is not commutative and thus it is not vector.
The mathematical rigid proof for 3d rotation not being vector must thus exist and can be learnt, by matrix or whatever.
However 2d rotation is commutative (there exist no counter example as far as I know), so how can it not be a vector? and how can proof exist (here, mine is not duplicate since my doubt is why is it so when there exist no physical reason) for 2d rotation not being vector when physically we are able to see it to be vector even for large angle?
An anticlockwise rotation can be denoted +ve,clockwise denoted -ve, and resultant of 2d rotation is sum of rotation with magnitude and sign(direction). On this basis 2d rotation is commutative just as addition is[eg. 2+(-3)=(-3)+2]
Please explain physically without complex maths

If a rotation through $2\pi$ is the same as no rotation at all, then the rotation cannot be a vector.

Thanks, got it.

@Peter . One is not obliged to identify rotations differing by $2 \pi$. In such a case, rotations in 2D can be represented by vectors.

I might be missing something.  "Rotation" denotes an operation.  "Vector" denotes a quantity, to physicists anyway.  That you can define an operation with notation that makes it look sort of like a vector does not make it a vector.  Look up "quaternions" and see if that provides an alternate labeling option.

The constraint "without complex math" is highly subjective. I'll take it to mean "without Geometric Algebra / Clifford Algebra" (which clarifies what is and what isn't a vector, and what rotates them, in arbitrary dimensions).
Choosing from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions, I like the "Vector Transformation Law" rotating a vector $p_i$ about an unit vector $n_i$ by an angle $\eta$:
$$p'_i = R_{ij}p_j $$
I don't think of $R_{ij}$ as a matrix, since it can be expressed in terms of the geometric vectors and scalars in the problem, along with the usually isotropic tensors, delta and epsilon:
$$R_{ij}(n_i, \eta) = 
n_in_j + \cos\eta\Big(
\delta_{ij} - n_in_j
\Big) +
\sin\eta\epsilon_{ijk}n_k
$$
Note that $n_i n_j$ is the projection operator onto $n_i$, and $\delta_{ij} - n_in_j$ is the rejection operator, aka "perpendicular component". The last term with Levi-Civitta symbols is a cross product.
So the rotation is not a vector, it's a rank-2 tensor, but it's not a pure rank-2 tensor (symmetric and traceless), as it has a trace (scalar part) and an antisymmetric part (which is an axial vector).
In 2D, there is no unit normal about which to rotate, which just have a number $\eta$...which may be a scalar. The $\delta_{ij}$ can be represented as an identity matrix:
$$ \delta_{ij} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
and the Levi-Civitta (aka fully anti-symmetric) symbol is:
$$ \epsilon_{ij} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
(Note: these are the only iso-tropic rank-2 tensors in 2 dimension).
From here, we can write the rotation operator as:
$$R_{ij}(\theta) = \cos\theta \delta_{ij} + \sin\theta\epsilon_{ij} $$
pretty easy.
What's the difference? The anti-symmetric symbol is rank-2 in 2D, so it can be inserted into the rotation operator directly.
In 3D, you need to contract it with the vector defining the rotation direction.
Edit: Now I need to was (semi)mathematical--but not with geometric algebra. Rotations are all about things we can rotate sensibly.
The easiest thing to rotate is the scalar, it's in fact, trivial:
$$ R(s) \rightarrow s$$
There is but 1 scalar in all dimensions.
The lowest non-trivial thing is a vector:
$$ R(v_i) \rightarrow R_{ij}v_j $$
In $N$ dimensions, there are $N$ of them, and we teach them as arrows, but they are better described as the 1st order waves on a surface of $N-1$. So in 2D, that's the two orthogonal vibrations on a circular ring:
$$ (\cos\theta, \sin\theta) $$
While in 3D, it's $x, y, z$, represented as:
$$\Big((Y_1^1+Y_1^{-1}), (Y_1^1-Y_1^{-1})/i, Y_1^0\Big) $$
plus normalization.
Up next is the tensors objects, which in 2D there are three(I'm guessing--actually, there are 2, ignore the middle):
$$ (\cos 2\theta, \cos \theta \sin \theta, \sin 2\phi)
$$ and in 3D, it's the five $l=2$ spherical harmonics.
The point is, when we take the tensor product of two vector representations in 3D, we get a tensor sum:
$$ {\bf 3}\times{\bf 3} = {\bf 5}_S + {\bf 3}_A + {\bf 1} $$
and our rotation operator is a combination of the objects on the right hand side, a trace free symmetric part from:
$$ {\bf 5}_S \rightarrow n_i n_j - \frac 1 2 n_k n_k $$
an antisymmetric vector-like part:
$$ {\bf 3}_A \rightarrow \sin\eta\epsilon_{ijk}n_k $$
an a scalar-like part:
$$ {\bf 1 }_S \rightarrow\cos\eta\delta_{ij}$$
Meanwhile, in 2 dimensions, we are used to:
$$ {\bf 2}\times{\bf 2} = {\bf 3}_S + {\bf 1}_A $$
when combining spinors (two spins make a triplet and a singlet). When the underlying vector space in $\mathbb{R}^2$, that triplet is made from $T_{xx}, T_{yy}, T_{xy}=T_{yx}$.
That can then have it's trace $T_{xx} + T_{yy}$ removed to get:
$$ {\bf 2}\times{\bf 2} = {\bf 2}_S + {\bf 1}_S + {\bf 1}_A $$
where we only need the latter two:
$${\bf 1}_S \rightarrow \cos\theta \delta_{ij}$$
$${\bf 1}_A \rightarrow \sin\theta \epsilon_{ij}$$
while the ${\bf 2}_S$ are related to the two shear transformation--I'm sure a mathematical physicist can wrap this up as obvious, but yeah, it's not for we experimentalists.
